# Proving two random variables are equal with probability $1$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Suppose we have two random variables such that $1 \leq X \leq Y$ almost surely. Now, suppose that all moments of $X$ and $Y$ exist, and,
>
> $$ E[Y^m] \leq E[X^m] + 1 $$
>
> for all $m \geq 1$. Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are equal almost surely.

By assumption, $Y \geq X$ almost surely, and so it suffices to prove that $X \geq Y$ almost surely. Specifically, I would like to show that $P\left(X > Y + \frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$ for all $n\geq1$. My attempt was to manipulate the Markov inequality,

$$ P\left(X > Y + \frac{1}{n}\right) \leq P\left(X > 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \dfrac{E[X^m]}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^m} \leq \dfrac{C}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^m}$$

The first inequality comes from the fact that $Y \geq 1$. **The last comes from the fact that $E[X^m] < \infty$ for all $m$**. Taking limits as $m \rightarrow \infty$ shows the desired result.

Am I justified in making the last inequality? Specificially, is what I said in bold above true? If the moments were uniformly bounded, then sure, but otherwise I can't be sure that the expression will go to zero.

Comment: Do we use at any point the given inequality involving the $m$-moments?

Comment: I did not in my "proof". Probably a red flag then.

Comment: How do you claim $E[X^m] \leq C$ for all $m$? Note that $2^m < \infty$ for all $m$, but that does not mean there is a constant $C$ such that $2^m \leq C$ for all $m$.

Comment: Instead, what if you write $Y=X+A$ where $A\geq 0$ almost surely, and use the remaining given info.  If you prove $E[A]=0$ you are done.

Comment: Ah, thank you providing a counterexample to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 
$$
Y^m-X^m=(Y-X)(Y^{m-1}+Y^{m-2}X+Y^{m-3}X^2\dots+X^{m-1})\ge (Y-X)m
$$
Therefore, 
$$
E[Y-X]\le \frac1m\cdot E[Y^m-X^m]\le \frac1m\qquad\text{for all }m\ge0
$$
Since $Y-X\ge0$ almost surely, the above implies $Y-X=0$. If you like, you can use the Markov inequality:
$$
P(Y-X>\epsilon)\le \frac{E[Y-X]}{\epsilon}\le \frac1{m\epsilon}\stackrel{m\to\infty}\longrightarrow0
$$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.